# Key events outside the browser?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I couldn't resolve this on Google, but is it possible to register key events happening outside the browser? Reason why is I got a new G19 gaming keyboard. It has a 5-inch LCD screen on which I use LCDHOST to show an HTML file on screen.

My issue here is that I wish to use JavaScript to detect key events so I can show different things when I'm in a game.

The HTML and JavaScript is local at my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the browser has focus you can get the events. If not you can't. To allow otherwise would be a HUGE security hole.

Comment: I know that, but the file is locally stored. So is there a way to implement it? I would really wanna know if there is a hack fix of some sort for local JavaScript execution.

Comment: I don't think it's likely that there is an exception for local files, as it has very little value (aside from your relatively rare case), and presents a terrible risk if there's a flaw in the implementation, or if a user is tricked into downloading and opening a file.

Comment: Basically you are asking for an html keylogger :)

Comment: One way i thought of doing it is to have a c++/c# program running finding my key press's. Then it would insert the event in a database which the JavaScript would then use ajax calls and PHP to get the events. Would this be my only option or is there other possible ways? Thanks :)

Comment: Well I'm sure you can construct a system involving your own local keylogger... One can also build a custom app and embed an IE browser in it, which can be driven by your keylogger, but your question was about browser events. Also you could add a keylogger to your own custom build of mozilla... it can be done, but not with simple javascript events.

Comment: Well my question was related to JavaScript as that is my tags. As the LCDHOST uses webkit to validate the JavaScript I'm not able to use any browsers at all. The reason why i said browser in my question is because the render of the LCD works sorta like a browser. At least it uses webkit. Think I'm stuck with a c# solution.